# Asp.NET DataTable query using linq

Tags: asp.net, linq, datatable, group-by

I need to do this query in linq on a DataTable object

```
Select * from mydatatable m where m.id==myid group by myField
```

If I try this code I have an error on CopyToDataTable()

```
int _idOrg=10;
DataTable dtAbb = (DataTable)ViewState["dtAbb "];
            var var_sez = from myRow in dtAbb .AsEnumerable()
                              group myRow by myRow.Field<string>("ID_IST") into newRow
                              where newRow.First().Field<int>("ID_ORG") == _idOrg
                              select newRow;
 DataTable dtSez = null;
 if (var_sez.Count() > 0)
     dtSezione = var_sez.AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Posting the error message would be a nice touch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `CopyToDataTable` on a seqence of groups of `DataRows` but only on `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. So you either have to take all rows from each group(but why do you group then at all) or use a specific row of each group. Here i take simply the first:

```
var var_sez = from myRow in dtAbb.AsEnumerable()
              where myRow.Field<int>("ID_ORG") == _idOrg
              group myRow by myRow.Field<string>("ID_IST") into grp
              select grp.First();
```

Note that i've also moved the `Where` before the `GroupBy`. You are selecting only groups where the first row's ID matches the given ID. I assume you wahnt only rows with this ID.
Hence this approach is "more corect" and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `ToDataTable` on your query result - you have to extend your LINQ a little.

"LINQ in Action" book has a nice code companion available [here](http://linqinaction.net/files/folders/linqinaction/entry1952.aspx). Download it, locate `ObjectShreder.cs` and `DataSetLinqOperators.cs` include them into your project and the methods become available to types other than `IEnumerable<DataRow>`

Reference: http://codecorner.galanter.net/2009/12/17/grouping-ado-net-datatable-using-linq/